# What is the deference in running time between regular expression implements eg. in Python and sed?

Tags: regex

I found that regex is a build-in for sed&awk and a library for Python, since they are both script language, what is the difference when I use those command on running time?

1.So, maybe you can tell me how a script language works in the running
    time.

for example:

```
sed -i 's/\.$/\!/g' regular_express.txt

#!/usr/bin/python
import re
phone = "2004-959-559 # This is Phone Number"
num = re.sub(r'#.*$', "", phone)
print "Phone Num : ", num
```

we assume that regular_express.txt:

```
#this is regular_expresss.txt

hello world.$
hello.$
```

2. For my question, My guess is(pseudocode):

```
read commands or code;
script interpreter translate commands into format;
if (is a build-in)
then call build-in function;
else call fork()&call library;
```

Am I right? Is the fork() used only for call library?

3.Why python have a regex library? Is it better for version management or for complicated function?

Comment: There is no "regular expression interpreter" and no separate process. Why do you think there is?

Comment: @melpomene Fine. I just guess there might be one since I can use the same regex in those command. So, is the regex a build-in code for every command and it's lib entity that I mentioned before?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking, but no, they don't use the same regex library, and in fact, their dialects differ on a number of points.  See the Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression -- under "Standards" you see BRE, SRE, and ERE but neither of these use the standard syntax.  There are even different `sed` dialects but they tend to support some sort of SRE or BRE, with ERE as a non-standard optional extension; Python uses a Perl-inspired variant, implemented by the PCRE library.

Comment: @tripleee Your comment helps.THX

Comment: You have changed your question a lot, and it's still not really clear where the focus is.  Really, there should only be one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a language is a script language doesn't necessarily dictate a particular implementation.  In fact, your examples differ; `sed` is a simple interpreter, while Python compiles your program to internal byte code, then executes that.

If you are asking specifically about how regular expression substitution is implemented, one component is obviously the regular expression engine, and another is the substitution component.  You are complicating matters by invoking the `-i` option of `sed`, but I'm guessing that's unintentional, and not the focus here.

The regular expression engine typically compiles your regex into a state machine, then applies that to the text you want to match.  The mapping between regular expressions and states in an automaton is a key concept which you will probably need to understand, but this box is really too small to explain that in any more detail.

Once there is a match, the substitution is fairly straightforward: Given indices into the string, extract the parts outside the match, and glue them around the substitution expression.  With regex back-references and script variables in the picture, there are a number of complications.

The reason you put code in a library is so that it can be reused.  Typically a library is executed in the same process as the calling code; there is no `fork()`, just code written by the library programmer, possibly linked into the executable from a binary-only library file (or in today's world, frequently dynamically loaded from a separate file during runtime), and the code which calls it .  Understanding code linking is again a separate, broad, and murky topic.  But in terms of your pseudocode, the only difference at that level is that the symbols in the library are provided from a separate binary blob during some phase of the linking and loading of the program.

By way of example, the PCRE library is a reimplementation of the Perl regular expression facility which originates from the Exim mail server.  The modular, reusable design of the library (as well as good documentation and reasonably robust implementation) has taken it places its author certainly did not originally envision.  Most libraries, though, see only limited use; a typical design is for a program to be divided into modules, where reusability is a secondary concern, and keeping different parts of the functionality in different layers is the main architectural reason to move some parts into separate libraries.

Comment: Very detailed answer.THX